# Retrieve Circle Points

Tags: opencv, geometry, points

In OpenCV, i know how to draw circles, but is there a way to get back all the points that makeup the circle? I hope I dont have to go through calculating contours.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know how to draw the circle,

1. Create a black image with the same size of as that of original image
2. Then draw the circle on the black image with white color
3. Now in this black image, check the points which are white

If you are using Python API, you can do as follows :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = np.zeros((500,500),np.uint8)
cv2.circle(img,(250,250),100,255)
points = np.transpose(np.where(img==255))
```

Comment: Oooh, just something I have thought of, I guess I will be stuck with this, nevertheless, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do similar thing to the [answer implemented in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083961/5472781) in C/C++

> If you know how to draw the circle,
>
> 1. Create a black image with the same size of as that of original image
> 2. Then draw the circle on the black image with white color

Now instead of checking which pixels have certain value you can find a contour (represented as vector of points) of the circle's edge.

To do this you can use OpenCV's [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) function which will give you the points on the circles edge.

Actually the background doesn't have to be black and the circle white, but the background should be plain and the circle should have different color than background.